# In ASP.Net, what is the proper way to use GridViews in conjuction with jQuery Templates?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, jquery-templates

What is the best way to use jQuery Templates with GridView to achieve similar functionality of an UpdatePanel, such as add/edit/delete data without PostBack?

Answer (score 0):

I would just use Ingrid along with a Repeater: http://www.reconstrukt.com/ingrid/

If you really need to utilize a Gridview, then go with the following link:

http://www.dotnetfunda.com/articles/article924-add-edit-delete-paging-records-in-gridview-using-jquery-.aspx

Comment: Don't use a repeater, use a ListView!